# rss weather for Mexico in conky

Tags: linux, rss, conky

I want to show the weather for my location, Ensenada, BC, Mexico on conky.
I have tried the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

METRIC=1 #Should be 0 or 1; 0 for F, 1 for C

if [ -z $1 ]; then
echo
echo "USAGE: weather.sh <locationcode>"
echo
exit 0;
fi

curl -s http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp\? 
metric\=${METRIC}\&locCode\=$1 | perl -ne 'if (/Currently/) {chomp;/\ 
<title\>Currently: (.*)?\<\/title\>/; print "$1"; }'
```

together with this code in .conkyrc:

```
${voffset 10}$alignr$color Los Angeles, CA: ${execi 300 
/usr/bin/weather.sh 347625}
```

347625 being the location code for Los Angeles and it works. 
However, if I use the code for my town 241911 it does not work because the accuweather sevice is not active anymore.

So, my question is: 
how do I modify the code to get the rss feeding from another website which displays the weather data for Ensenada, Mexico?

Comment: Try it: ``curl wttr.in`` (https://github.com/schachmat/wego)

Comment: Thanks, pretty cool app, but how would I show that in conky?